# SQL Server stored procedure with default values

Tags: sql-server, jpa

I Have SQL Server stored procedure with ~100 parameters, with default values. I have to pass only 3 of them. Is it possible to use StoredProcedureQuery? Now if I have procedure:

```
create procedure MyProc(@Param1 varchar(30) = "test", @Param2 smallint = 1, @Param3 char = 'a', @Param4 char = 'b',
                              @Param5 varchar(50) = "test", @Param6 tinyint = 7, @Param7 varchar(3) = "tes", @Param8 varchar(3) = "ADS",
                              @Param9 varchar(50) = "TEST", @Param10 varchar(8) = "TEST", @Param11 varchar(222) = "TEST")
```

and executing procedure like this:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedureQuery = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
                    .createStoredProcedureQuery("MyProc");
    
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Param9", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter("Param9", "test9");
    
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Param10", Character.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter("Param10", "test10");
    
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Param11", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
                    .setParameter("Param11", "test11");
```

Unfortenatly value "test9" goes to @Param1, "test10" goes to @Param2 and "test11" goes to @Param3.

Is it possible to pass parameters by name, not by position?

Comment: None of the parameters in that `CREATE` you've provided have a default value.

Comment: Do you mean `= 'test'`? Double quotes (`"`) are used as object delimit identifiers, not for literal strings; single quotes (`'`) are for literal strings.

Comment: Yes, main question is is it possible to pass parameters by name, not by position using JPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to pass parameters by name using JPA and SQL Server using NativeQuery.

```
Query query = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().createNativeQuery("""
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[MyProc]
        @Param9 = :Param9,
        @Param10 = :Param10,
        @Param11 = :Param11
""");

query.setParameter("Param9", "test9");
query.setParameter("Param10", "test10");
query.setParameter("Param11", "test11");
```